# Difference between "points" and "elements" of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a rather pedantic question, but I want to be sure I'm using the term correctly. Rudin seems to call elements of not a general set, but a metric space "points" instead of elements. My professor suggested that "points" is used for "spaces" as opposed to sets, which I believe is a set plus some structure, be it a metric, a topology, and so forth. With that said, I've seen elements of general sets called points, and the usage in Rudin and elsewhere isn't completely
clear to me.

My question is: what is the convention? Is this only for spaces or for general sets?

Comment: There is nothing wrong  in using the two words interchangeably.

Comment: If we apply the language of sets to geometry, i.e. to the description of *spaces*, we have that lines and planes are sets of *points*.

Comment: With this approach, a point lying on a line is an element of the "line set" and a line is an element of a "plane set".

Comment: There is a difference between showing that mathematics has sound foundations in set theory, and in contrast being conscious of those foundations when doing your mathematics. The language of mathematical disciplines involved defining and considering concepts which enable fluent analysis and description of mathematical phenomena. The work of showing that this can be made consistent with set theoretical language is something which only needs to be done once. In parallel to your example, a function can be defined as a set of ordered pairs ...

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the *elements* or members of a set can themselves be sets which in turn themselves have sets as members, etc. In other words, in the general case, the elements of a set can themselves be items with internal structure.

By contrast, we normally think of a *point* as an item with no internal structure (remember Euclid's definition of a point as that which has no parts).

So I wouldn't say that we can simply use "elements" and "points" interchangeably.

Rather, when we do talk of the members of some set as points, either (i) we are thinking of the those elements as actually being structureless items, or at least (ii) we are taking it that in the current context, for current purposes, we can ignore any internal composition they have and treat them *as if* structureless.

Comment: What about points in analytic geometry? Those points are vectors, aka tuples of real numbers. :) What's worse, a real number can be considered a special family of sequences of rational numbers, which in turn are pairs of integer numbers...

Comment: @CiaPan: the coordinates of a point in analytic geometry should be thought of as just a description of the point from an outsider perspective, rather than an inherent feature of the point. We have to choose a coordinate system for points to have meaningful coordinates, but the points exist before we choose a coordinate system in the first place.